# Md5 inside a for loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, hash, md5

I have a for loop with example user array and I want to md5 the password but the thing is, it is hashing the password twice. I want only once the `md5($_POST[2]);`

```
    user([userid, username, password]); 

    $num_fields =3; 
     for ($y = 1; $y < $num_fields; $y++) {
           $password = md5($_POST[2]);
           $_POST[2] = $password;
            }
```

Example input for password is `user` and the output is

```
ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee0d8d5cd06832b29560745fe4e1b941cf
```

Instead of

```
ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee
```

My solution is

```
   for ($y = 1; $y < $num_fields; $y++) {
          $password = md5($_POST[2]);
          $_POST[2] = $password;
          return $_POST[2];
            }
```

But I don't want the `return $_POST[2];` and break the loop for mysql insert purposes inside the loop. So my question is, how to md5 once on a loop without return and get the only md5 value?

Comment: why loop here and also try using hash instead of md5.

Comment: `md5()` is **not** safe anymore, use `password_hash()` and `pasword_verify()` instead. `md5()` is easily decrypted these days.

Comment: @Nytrix this is just for learning purposes to login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loop. You don't use `$y` variable. And variable `$num_fields` in condition makes the loop run twice (for `$y` equal 1 and 2).

This should do what you expect:

```
user([userid, username, password]); 
$password = md5($_POST[2]);
$_POST[2] = $password;
```

## UPDATE

If you need that loop for some reason, just create the md5 before loop. I changed initialization of `$y` to 0 because it makes more sence to loop three times when `$num_fields` is set to 3. But you can have reason which I can't see from the sample.

```
user([userid, username, password]); 

$password = md5($_POST[2]);
$_POST[2] = $password;
$num_fields = 3;

for ($y = 0; $y < $num_fields; $y++) {
    // Anything you wanted to loop
}
```

As @nitrix said, md5 isn't save anymore. But if it's project only for learning how to create login or high security isn't required then it's ok.

Comment: @MarkValenzuela if this works, could you, please, accept the answer provided? This site is based on that, you know.